# Finding the largest circle fitting in a polygon.

Tags: geometry

Consider a polygon with $N$ sides, and you are given all the angles within it $(a_1,a_2,a_3 \dots a_N)$ and the sides $s_1,s_2,s_3 \dots s_N$. How do you find the largest circle that fits inside it?

For example, the radius of the largest circle that will fit in a square with side length $n $ is $\frac{n}{2}$

Comment: This question was asked on stack overflow with at least one good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279478/largest-circle-inside-a-non-convex-polygon

Comment: @MatthewConroy It'd have been nice to precise which answer was "good" ! I personally like the answer with Voronoi diagrams since they may point to an exact answer, whereas the other answers seem to focus on a practical implementation...?

Comment: @N.Bach I was just going off the upvotes: people seem to like some of the answers there.  I thought I was being helpful by just pointing out the source of information, but this is how things go: people criticize you for not doing more, instead of thanking you for what you do.

Comment: @MatthewConroy Wow, don't take it so negatively. Imo constructive criticism should always be welcomed in this kind of community, since it helps in improving your knowledge and answers. I thought I'd just add a tiny bit to your answer to give more information to OP. Of course people should be thankful when others try to help, but to keep information concise I usually only upvote people. The link you found and provided was plenty relevant and helpful. Remains to know what kind of answer OP wants.

Comment: @N.Bach You're welcome! Cheers!